# revert the custom fields made by sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

It is very simple task to create a custom field in sugarCRM through studio. What i want is vice versa . I want to revert the custom fields made by studio by changing code and databases ?

One simple method i found is simply delete the fields from vardef and delete the related columns from the database but i am not sure if it will work and not be cause of problems in future.

Can anyone come up with any reliable solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete fields thru Studio with ease.

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/04_Sugar_Professional/Sugar_Professional_6.5/Administration_Guide/07_Developer_Tools/01_Studio#Fields

Comment: Thank's for reply @jmertic , But I have done that many times. If i delete fields from studio they still remain in the database , I want to fully revert fields.

Comment: At that point just manually delete it from the database as you are already doing.

Comment: Thank's ,I note it now that in sugarCRM version 6.5.0 it removed it from databases completely.

Comment: The page jmertic is referring to is now empty. Along with many other pages in that section.

Comment: Sorry about that, our KB solution is giving us fits. We are working on fixing that as quickly as possible. Here's an updated link http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/04_Sugar_Professional/Sugar_Professional_6.5/Administration_Guide/07_Developer_Tools/01_Studio#Fields